# How to teleport player to different scene via trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have used the most traditional method of doing this but it doesn't work. No response is initiated.

I've attached a rigidbody2d collider (with 0.0001 mass and no drag or gravity) to my player sprite and a box collider 2d with is trigger checked.

Sidenote:  Outdoor1" is the name of the scene I want to teleport my player to.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TeleportToScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string newScene;

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag ("Player"))
        {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Outdoor1");
```

I expect it to go over the box collider and change scenes but nothing happens. No error messages either.

Comment: Did you try debugging? Is the tag correct? Is `OnTriggerEnter` called at all?

Comment: Oh and your script is attached to the player object right?

Comment: @derHugo I've tried debugging and `OnTriggerEnter` isn't called at all.  Firstly, my script was only attached to collider cube but now that you mention it I attached it to both but still no progress.

Comment: It has to be attached to the object which is not a trigger. If both colliders are triggers it won't work at all - one of them has to be not a trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make OnTriggerStay2D you need to have an collider 2D set to trigger on the object who as the script TeleportToScene and a Rigidbody2D

So you scene will be, 2 object:

1.Player with
 - Deplacement
 - Collider2D(not trigger)
 - Tag "Player"

2.Teleporter with
 - TeleportToScene.cs
 - Collider2D (trigger)
 - Rigidbody2D (kinematic)

Hope that help !